# Unhide Excel Rows Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA script on Excel 2011 For Mac and having limited success.

Depending on the value in cell A1, the script needs to unhide the rows below.

```
If A1 = 1, it needs to unhide row B.
If A1 = 2, it needs to unhide rows B and C.
If A1 = 3, it needs to unhide rows B, C and D.
```

...and so on, up to a maximum A1 value of 8.

The values in A1 use data validation to be looked up from a list elsewhere on the sheet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you say `B, C, D`, it seems you mean *Columns*, not *Rows*.

You can use this:

```
Range("B1").Resize(1, Range("A1")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Sorry, it was columns that I wanted to hide.

Based on the value in AE25, I want to unhide rows 26-28 if the value is 1, rows 26-29 if the value is 2, rows 26-30 if the value is 3, and so on, up to 8.

Comment: So what now, _Columns_? _Rows_? _Hide_? _Unhide_? If you still need help, please edit your question and describe precisely what you need. And try adapt my example to your new (?) request, then you'll get help where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Case Range("A1").Value

   Case 1
      Range("A2").EntireRow.hidden = false      
   Case 2
      Range("A2,A3").EntireRow.hidden = false

   '...   

   Case Else
      MsgBox("Invalid number in cell A1")

End Select
```

in this case A2 would refer to row 2, A2,A3 would be 2 and 3 etc etc

EDIT:

per your comment maybe something like this would be better

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim val as Integer

val = Range("AE25").Value
if (val >= 1) then
  set rng = Range("A26:A27").Resize(val,0)
  rng.EntireRow.Hidden = false
end if
```

Comment: Sorry, it was columns that I wanted to hide.

Based on the value in AE25, I want to unhide rows 26-28 if the value is 1, rows 26-29 if the value is 2, rows 26-30 if the value is 3, and so on, up to 8.